# While running Compiled MatLab from console window, prompt returns immediately while app is still running

Tags: matlab

I have compiled my simple MatLab function so I can run it from a Windows console as a command line app. After I enter the command and its single argument, the prompt returns immediately even though the command is still running, as if running in the background.

Can someone tell me why this happens and how do I stop it? I'd like it to behave like a normal application and not return to the prompt until complete.

EDIT: Sorry I didn't post the code previously, I figured I was making a common mistake and would get a quick answer. Anyway, here it is.

It translates a .mat file to a .csv file and then runs another console command via "system" to perform a quick edit on the resulting .csv file. Several minutes of IO but not much else.

I've never compiled MatLab before so probably something simple, I hope.

```
function WriteMatToCSV( inFile, overWrite )

if ~exist(inFile, 'file')
     fprintf('Error File not found: %s\n',inFile);
     return;
end

overWriteExisting = 1;
if exist('overWrite','var')
    overWriteExisting = overWrite;
end

% Change file extension
outFile = strrep( inFile, '.mat','.csv');
fprintf('In : %s\n',inFile);
fprintf('Out: %s\n',outFile);

% Overwrite if exists?
if exist(outFile, 'file')
    if ~overWriteExisting
        fprintf('Error File exists: %s\n',outFile);
        return;
    end
end

% Get variable name in the file
matObj = matfile(inFile);
info = whos(matObj);
name = info.name;
fprintf('Found variable: %s\n',name);

% Load the variable from the file
fprintf('Loading mat...\n');
load(inFile);

% Write the variable to .csv file
fprintf('Writing csv...\n');
export(eval(name),'File',outFile','Delimiter',',');

fprintf('Rewriting to remove MatLab bits...\n');
command = 'RewriteMatLabCSV';
command = [command ' ' outFile];
[status,cmdout] = system(command,'-echo');
fprintf(cmdout);

fprintf('Done\n');
end
```

Comment: Are you sure, that the application is still running and has not crashed? Can you please post your simple application? Do you return an exit code?

Comment: @bushmills It is definitely still running: it takes several minutes and prints out several messages while it is running. I do not return an exit code. I will post the code shortly.

Comment: And your code is working fine, so your file is written correctly and the application prints out "Done"?

Comment: Yes. Everything runs fine, as I said. The results are fine.